# Given a graph, identify users more likely to connect to a new user

Tags: probability, graph-theory, social-network

I have some twitter-like data described as tuples of users (u1, u2), that means u1 follows u2. I also have a second dataset with another list of tuples (r1, r2), that means user r1 frequently click on r2, yet does not follows r2. With these two pieces on data, I'd like to identify those r1 users from the second dataset that might be more likely to want to follow r2. In general terms, how do I go about approaching this type of problem?

Comment: What other variables do you have? I guess you must have a lot of covariables, and maybe a lot of data, such that it is practical  to divide the data in training and test sets.

Comment: The way I'm being asked to solve the problem limits the data to the graph tuples, and the frequent clickers tuples. I'm asked to make the most of it. I don't think this is a machine learning problem, more of a link prediction problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without covariables, there do not seem to be much information.  If a specific $r_1$ do not appear at all as a $u_1$, then maybe he doesn't like to follow people, so the probability is low.  If he appears many times, maybe the probability is high.

So, some ideas.  For a specific pair of users $(a_1, a_2)$ you want the probability $p(a_1, a_2)$ that $a_1$ will start following $a_2$ at some future time (better specify when, or else will not be well defined).  Define three variables (for this pair):
$$   \\  
   x=\text{number of times $a_1$ clicked on $a_2$}  \\
   y=\text{number of times $a_1$ appear as a follower of somebody, eg, as a $u_1$}  \\
   z=\text{number of times $a_2$ appear as being followed, eg, as a $u_2$}   \\
$$
will be some increasing function of $x, y, z$. You might try a logistic function, or something else.  Hope I have understood the problem well, at least this might be a start.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even have counts of clicks. I just know r1 clicked "many" times on r2. I understand this is coming across like a theoretical exercise, but this is the problem I'm tasked with. How about just looking at the number of common neighbors in the graph?

Comment: You can still do what I propsed, but with $x$ as a $0-1$ variable.